# Session for windows forms application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, session

Is there a session for Windows based applications for C# in order to record the details of log in in and log out for multiple users?

I tried to use declaring static variables, but it is not the same as a session.

Comment: use a logging mechanism, such as log4net.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no concept of session variables in Windows Forms. You can do:

Create a static class that holds the user name and password and any other variables needed across the application.

In your case it would be something like:

```
public static class LoginInfo
{
    public static string UserID;
}
```

Now you can access the UserID simply from anywhere in your code:

```
MessageBox.Show(LogInfo.UserID);
```

Or set the values after login like:

```
LogInfo.UserID = TextBox1.Text;
```

Comment: hi.. if i installed this application in two different machines. will the static variable be the same as the first machine when both machine is access by different users?

Comment: I dont think so,bcos static is 'static per AppDomain' ,Use database store techniques if your application point to a db in network of all installed instances of your application.

Comment: G8 sounds like Gate. Maybe you meant Gr8? :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no session variables in a normal Windows application (the way there is in a web application). If you need logging for a Windows application I agree with the previously written comment to use some logging framework like log4net, NLog or something like that. Even using the Eventlogs can be an option, but I don't recommend it.