# How to create a session for a specific user in C#.NET application Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, winforms, session, datagridview

I have a login form containing two fields textBox1.Text and textBox2.Text one is used for username and other for password. I now want to create a session for a specific user and load his own personal data into the application forms DataGridView. I am already using following code for loading values and inserting them in database . 
Code for Form Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from fianlTable WHERE @UsernameFromLoginForm = DataTableMatchingValue ", con);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;    
}
```

Code for insertion :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO fianlTable ( AccountNumber, Date, CustomerName, Credit, Debit,  Balance, Address) VALUES
    (@CustomerID, '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "',(SELECT Name FROM TableCustomer WHERE (CustomerID like '" + textBox1.Text + "' )) ,'" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "', (SELECT Address FROM TableCustomer WHERE (CustomerID like '" + textBox1.Text + "' ))  )", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",  Name   );

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I want to modify the code so that I may login from a login form and a session starts, The code should automatically retrieve username from textBox1.Text of Login form and insert username throughout the session . All the above code works fine . I want to create a session for a particular user for particular entries by the user.I am a PHP Developer, in php we use $_POST and $_GET for getting specific values from other forms and also used session variables . How to do it in Visual Studio C#.NET

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad for understanding your question. For window form please go here: [Session for windows forms application in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599127/session-for-windows-forms-application-in-c-sharp)

This is for web form:

You just use [`Session`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
You will find it very simple to use.

In your login.aspx form, when user type username, password and click button "Login":

```
Session["name_of_user"] = txtName.Text;
```

When you check authentication and login's success, at any other forms you can get the `Session["test"]` again (in code behind aspx.cs)

```
lblWelcome.Text = "Hello, " + Session["name_of_user"];
```

ASP Session start when user go to your website, not **after** login - authentication

> ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist variable values for the duration of that session. By default, ASP.NET session state is enabled for all ASP.NET applications.

Comment: I have to get name_of_user from textBox.Text which is on LoginForm and Session to be started is On CustomerForm and also data to be loaded in DataGridView must be for that particular User . Please explain the hint looks incomplete to me. Same scenario for insertion.

Comment: @Mohammad Shahid: sorry my bad but you are working with `window from` not `web form` ? Then you should create a `static class` like [suggestion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599127/session-for-windows-forms-application-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Probably I forgot to mention it's not Asp.NET its's C# windows form application exactly.

Comment: @MuhammadShahid Then you need create a static class , it will keep all your variable as long as user don't close your application