# disabling a button using database entities users C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am working on a project for my studies and I have multiple logins an Administrator and Teacher. This project has multiple winforms the 2 I am needing help with is my Login and the Main form after the user logs in.
I have already created the logins and they work but I need to disable a button called btnMarks int he Main form the Administrator cannot have access to this button.
I have tried if statements but I can't seem to make it work. I am using radio buttons for logins as well as the Administrator and Teachers logins have their own tables in the database. I can only use Entities not SQLconnections it is part of the project for my studies.

Please help

Below is my user login form code.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //A check to make sure both fields have an entry
        if(txtUsername.Text == "" || txtPassword.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please provide a Username and Password!");
            return;
        }
        //This is to call the boolean radiobuttons are checked
        radioButtons();

        //Teachers login
        if (rbTeachers.Checked)
        {
            int Username = Convert.ToInt32(txtUsername.Text);
            SchoolDBEntities db = new SchoolDBEntities();
            var tid = from t in db.Teachers
                      where t.TID == Username
                      && t.Password == txtPassword.Text
                      select t;

            if (tid.Any())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in as a Teacher!");
                this.Hide();
                Main tss = new Main();
                tss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password!");
            }
        }

        //Administrator login
        if (rbAdmin.Checked)
        {
            int Username = Convert.ToInt32(txtUsername.Text);
            SchoolDBEntities db = new SchoolDBEntities();
            var aid = from a in db.Administrators
                      where a.AID == Username
                      && a.Password == txtPassword.Text
                      select a;

            if (aid.Any())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in as Administrator");
                this.Hide();
                Main tss = new Main();
                tss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password");
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my Main form, I need the btnMarks button disabled for Administrators.
I am unsure where to put the code to disable this button as well. If I could be able to call the radio button from the login form please show me how.

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnMarks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmStudentMarks marks = new frmStudentMarks();

        marks.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you making something like `SessionManagement` object to manage current session ( logged user, user rights etc. ).

```
public static class SessionManagement
{
    static UserEntity sessionUser = null;

    public static void LoggedAs(UserEntity user)
    {
        sessionUser = user;
    }
    // other methods/fields to manage session
}
```

After doing this you can just set session for currently logged user :

```
var tid = from t in db.Teachers
          where t.TID == Username
          && t.Password == txtPassword.Text
          select t;
SessionManagement.LoggedAs((UserEntity)tid); // make some explicit operators or something.
```

Now you have full control over who is logged in and you can check it's rights so all you have to do is to check it after `InitializeComponent()` method call :

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    btnMarks.Enabled = !SessionManagement.CurrentUser.IsAdministrator;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You've asked if there's something else you should do for this code to make it works. Answer is **yes**. This answer is basically a scheme for you to work something out. But since it's not an easy thing to do I'll explain it in somewhat more details.

Firstly, you have 2 types of `Entity`: `Teacher` and `Administrator` and you need to make one *"unified"* entity ( I named it `UserEntity` ). This unified entity should be convertible from both `Teacher` and `Administrator` entity.

My recommendation in code :

```
public class UserEntity
{
    string _username;
    public string Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
    }

    bool _isAdministrator;
    public bool IsAdministrator
    {
        get { return _isAdministrator; }
    }

    public UserEntity(Administrator entity)
    {
        _isAdministrator = true;
        _username = entity.AID;
    }

    public UserEntity(Teacher entity)
    {
        _isAdministrator = false;
        _username = entity.TID;
    }

    public static explicit operator UserEntity(Administrator entity)
    {
        return new UserEntity(entity);
    }

    public static explicit operator UserEntity(Teacher entity)
    {
        return new UserEntity(entity);
    }
}
```

Now you can do somehting like `UserEntity userEntity = (UserEntity)teacher;`

Next thing to do is to update `SessionManagement` by adding new method into it :

```
public static void LoggedAs(UserEntity entity)
{
    if(sessionUser != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot be logged 2 times with the same session");

    sessionUser = entity;
}
```

And a property :

```
public static UserEntity CurrentUser 
{
    get { return sessionUser; }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to combine all of these into one huge chunk of code :

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
// parts of your code till this line :
SchoolDBEntities db = new SchoolDBEntities();
var tid = from t in db.Teachers
          where t.TID == Username
          && t.Password == txtPassword.Text
          select t;
Teacher teacher = tid.FirstOrDefault();
if(teacher != null)
{
    SessionManagement.LoggedAs((UserEntity)teacher);
}
// do the same with Administrator
```

Now since `SessionManagement` is static object you can use it everywhere inside your application and it will persist with all stored data meaning you can use :

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    btnMarks.Enabled = !SessionManagement.CurrentUser.IsAdministrator;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this and see how it goes

Comment: I have tried it but i am getting errors with the `btnMarks.Enabled` after `!SessionManagement` i don't get many options, is there something i have missed?

Comment: I'm guessing that you haven't made `CurrentUser` field/property inside `SessionManagement` object or you didn't make `IsAdministrator` field/property inside `UserEntity`

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused is there something else I need to do with the code to make this work?

Comment: thanks for that update I will give it a go and let you know how it all goes, really appreciate the help.

Comment: everything is good apart from an error I am getting the name `CurrentUser` does not exist in current context

Comment: @DanielOrlicki because it didn't had any return type. Fixed it now.

Comment: you are awesome thanks for your help it works fantastic, i understand and have learnt a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain a static class for that in which you can add that the current user's type.

Kindly go through the following url

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599474/1526972

Comment: I tried to follow this link but it didn't work the way i wanted it to thanks @Ikram Shah

Answer (score 0):

The command button, by default, has a public access level so you can access and disable it from login form before to call the Show() method in this way:

```
tss.yourButtonName.Enabled = false;
```

Hope this help.
Christian

Comment: Now consider that magically `yourButtonName` is a `private` field?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work either thanks @jacktric